# Drop down data is not listing if open the template via "Google sheets"

Tags: excel, typescript, exceljs

When i open the excel sheet via "Google sheet" the drop down data is not populating showing as “loading". This is a part of my code to generate this list:

```
importSheet.getCell(`E${i + 2}`).dataValidation = {
      type: 'list',
      allowBlank: false,
      formulae: [` IF(ISBLANK(D${i + 2}),"",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(LEFT(D${i + 2},10),"Col")))`]
    }
```

And in Lookup sheet

```
workbook.definedNames.add(`Lookup!$A$2:$A$${lookupData.ItemCodes.length + 1}`, `MaterialCol`)
workbook.definedNames.add(`Lookup!$B$2:$B$${lookupData.Attachments.length + 1}`, `AttachmentCol`)
```

Some images of this issue:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv3tB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dino0.png)

If i opened the material template via Google Sheet, How i able to view the drop down data as expects? This is work when open with Microsoft Office and Office 365